# How to store variable in GB in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create script to deploy virtual machines on my computer. I'm stuck with my memory size variable being stored as string and not recognized by the New-VM cmdlet. Can someone point me to the right direction please.

```
$VMName = Read-Host -Prompt 'VM Name'
$Memory = Read-Host -Prompt 'Set Memory Allocation (GB)'
$VMDirectory = 'C:\My VMs'
New-VM -Name $VMName -MemoryStartupBytes "$Memory" -Path $VMDirectory -Generation 2 -SwitchName $SwitchName -NoVHD
```

I'm getting an error

> New-VM : Cannot bind parameter 'MemoryStartupBytes'. Cannot convert
> value "4GB" to type "System.Int64". Error: "Input string was not in a
> correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the string to an int:

```
$VMName = Read-Host -Prompt 'VM Name'
$Memory = [int64](Read-Host -Prompt 'Set Memory Allocation (GB)')
$VMDirectory = 'C:\My VMs'
New-VM -Name $VMName -MemoryStartupBytes $Memory -Path $VMDirectory -Generation 2 -SwitchName $SwitchName -NoVHD
```

Comment: With the OP's input: `4GB` (per error message), this throws the same error. If the user enters an integer specifiy the number of GB, you should convert it to bytes before passing to `New-VM`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're inputing the value as "4GB", you can use [`Invoke-expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.3):

```
PS C:\> $Memory = Invoke-Expression(Read-Host -Prompt 'Set Memory Allocation (GB)')

Set Memory Allocation (GB): 4GB

PS C:\> $memory
4294967296

PS C:\> $memory.GetType().Name
Int64

PS C:\> $Memory / 1MB
4096
```

---

---

## Edit per dire warnings!!!

If you code in not for personal use, you'll want to screen the input to avoid malicious code:

```
$MemString = (Read-Host -Prompt 'Set Memory Allocation (GB)').Trim()

If ( $MemString -match '^\d+\s*(gb|mb|kb)$' )
{
    $Memory = Invoke-Expression("$MemString")
}
ElseIf ( $MemString -match '^\d+$' )  # assume int specifies GB per prompt
{
    $Memory = [int]$MemString * 1GB
}
Else
{
   ## <Error message & handling>
}
$memory
```

Comment: One should always [Avoid using Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression). This way you are allowing the user to type in any command and it will get executed..

Comment: @Theo: Did you note the input that threw the error? `"4GB"? Did you notice that Paolo's answer produces the same error with the same input? I linked to the documentation that provids the same warning. I assumed the OP was creating a VM for their own testing and would not sabotage their own machine!. Nevertheless, I shall ammend slightly.

Comment: Sure, if a user types in `"4GB"` you'll get the error. Therefore you should never trust user input and at least make sure only digits were typed in. Using Invoke-Expression directly on the user's input (_any_ input) however is definitely not a good idea IMO. BTW, I didn't downvote in case you wonder, I only wanted to point out that what you propose is very dangerous.